# How to draw tic tac toe lines graphics.py (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics, tic-tac-toe

I have lines drawn with the coordinate system set up as `win.setCoords(0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 3.0)`. The lines are drawn according to that system. But I need the coordinate system to be on a bigger system, like 1000 instead of 3 as the max. How do i draw the lines to the tic tac toe board with the system being `win.setCoords(0.0, 0.0, 1000.0, 1000.0)` ? Mind you the code below is not written by me, which is why I'm having the problem.

```
from graphics import *
import random

def draw_board(winsize, win):
    win.setCoords(0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 3.0)
    win.setBackground('white')
    # Draw the vertical lines
    Line(Point(1,0), Point(1,3)).draw(win)
    Line(Point(2,0), Point(2,3)).draw(win)
# Draw the horizontal lines
    Line(Point(0,1), Point(3,1)).draw(win)
    Line(Point(0,2), Point(3,2)).draw(win)
    if winsize < 100:
        win.close()
    if winsize > 1000:
        win.close()

def player_turns(draw_board, win, winsize):
    c = 9
    for i in range(c):
        if c%2==0:
            print("Player two take your turn")
            player1 = win.getMouse()
            play1x=player1.getX()
            play1y=player1.getY()
            #play1.draw(win)
            print(player1)
            if play1x < (winsize/3) and play1y < (winsize/3):
                    circ = Circle(Point(0.4757929883138564, 
                    2.5242070116861437), .25)
                    circ.setOutline('red')
                    circ.draw(win)
            elif play1x < (winsize/3) and play1y < ((winsize/3)*2):
                    circ = Circle(Point(0.44488977955911824, 
                    1.5330661322645291), .25)
                    circ.setOutline('red')
                    circ.draw(win)

        else:
            print('Player one take your turn')
            play2 = win.getMouse()
            play2x=play2.getX()
            play2y=play2.getY()
            #play2.draw(win)
            if play2x < (winsize/3) and play2y < (winsize/3):
                    circ = Circle(Point(0.4757929883138564, 
                    2.5242070116861437), .25)
                    circ.setOutline('blue') 
                    circ.draw(win)
            elif play2x < (winsize/3) and play2y < ((winsize/3)*2):
                    circ = Circle(Point(0.44488977955911824, 
                    1.5330661322645291), .25)
                    circ.setOutline('blue') 
                    circ.draw(win)
            print(play2)
        c=c-1
def main():
    winsize = int(input("Input the size of the window: "))
    win = GraphWin("Tic-Tac-Toe", winsize, winsize)
    draw_board(winsize, win)
    player_turns(draw_board, win, winsize)



main()
```

Comment: Can you post the complete source code? What are the dependencies? What is `win`?

Comment: @Nepho Added the source code.